# How to train parallel series together using fbprophet library?

Tags: python, time-series, data-science, anomaly-detection, facebook-prophet

I have a time-series that recorded at the same timestamps (12:00 12:15 12:30 ..) of different days (1.Monday, 2.Monday, 3.Monday ...). I want to train time-series of "Monday", teach the model behaviour of recorded value on that day, detect outliers with the trained model. How can I do that? thanks!

I can train the model with each time-series but in that case, I lose information on other days.